# The fastest way how to check how many words in string array is in the correct place

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, kotlin

I have a string:

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

And a random method, which are mixing these words in the array.

`brown` `jumps` `over` `The` `lazy` `fox` `quick` `the` `dog`

What is the fastest way to check which ones words are in the correct place using `java` or `kotlin` ?

**EDIT**

I mean `Correct mutual order`

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Title says "correct order" but question says "correct place". Which is it? --- Also, why does random method change the case of a word, i.e. `The` to `the`?

Comment: So you need performance boost over easy solution? If not, why don't you match them in a linear manner?

Comment: Do you need correct places or correct mutual order?

Answer (score 2):

One Solution would be comparing the original with the new Array returning from the method.

```
    String[] original = {"The", "quick", "Brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
    String[] mixed = mixArray(original);
    ArrayList<String> sameOrder = new ArrayList<>();
    int wordsInTheSameOrder = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
        if(original[i].equals(mixed[i])) {
            sameOrder.add(original[i]);
            wordsInTheSameOrder++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin if:

```
val str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
val list = str.split(" ")

val strShuffled = "over jumps brown The lazy fox quick the dog"
val listShuffled = strShuffled.split(" ")
```

then:

```
val listMatching = list.filterIndexed { index, s ->  s.equals(listShuffled[index])}

println(listMatching.size)
println(listMatching)
```

will print  
 
`2
[brown, dog]`

The above code filters only the elements from the list that are equal with the element in the shuffled list in the exact same position and counts the size of the filtered list.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way in Java probably uses a `HashMap` to store each word in the sentence. You'd want to use the word as the **key** and the place in the sentence as the **value**. This would require 1 pass of the original sentence (an O(n) operation).

Since words might appear twice, you can actually create a `List` of words.

This solution should work for any sentence. If you only care about that particular sentence, you might be fine just using a `for` loop and comparing array index values.

Comment: This looks like an overkill. You could instead have a map of `place->word` mapping, which is actually already there - it's an array (or a List).

Comment: It is O(n) in any case, no need for a HashMap

Comment: Yeah I read the question a bit wrong before the edit. I was thinking you might have 2 different sets of words, which would then require a Map to check that the key exists in the first sentence.